# No bootsplash screen shown when starting Ubuntu on HP laptop

Tags: boot, intel-graphics, plymouth

I use Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP 6730s: I have a problem shown in this Youtube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0eQ3FnrUQo

The video shows my computer booting up, showing the HP logo, then a black screen for quite a while, then the LightDM log in screen.

Is it becausee I have no video card driver? I can't install it, it's the Intel 4 mobile chipset family.

Comment: looks like only the Plymouth boot screen (splash screen saying "Ubuntu") is not showing, but that is superfluous. It boots, it works. (and this not showing is sometimes a symptom of having the right driver)

Comment: @mateo_salta Yeah for me I never see that when I use either the Intel or Nvidia drivers. Don't know if it is because it loads fast or simply skipped altogether to... speed up boot time?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after seeing the video all I can say is:

1. Ubuntu loaded without any problems (Not even video problems)
2. Intel drivers, including for your mobile version are already installed automatically once you install Ubuntu. If they had any problems, you would not be able to even load the Desktop, the Unity Launcher or any other GUI parts that need video.
3. The video for me basically proved that you **do** have video. There is no need to install it (at least for Intel). This is not windows where you need to install every driver for every hardware part that exists in your PC/Laptop or device.